# How to list (search) files with a certain name

Tags: search, visual-studio-code, file-search

i'm trying to get a list of all the files with a certain name in a project i opened with VS Code.

For example, all the .gitignore files in my project. I know i can <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> and type ".gitignore", but i don't want to open all the files, i want to list them, and open them one by one afterwards. Also the "open file" popup disappears as it looses focus and brings recent files to the top, altering the order every time (this makes it difficult to keep track of the files i already opened).

I've found [this cool extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bcanzanella.openmatchingfiles) that only *opens* all the files with a certain name (it even supports wildcards). The problem is that i have tens of files, i can't open all of them together, especially if the files are not simple .gitignore files, but something bigger.

Yes i could just use my OS' file search, but that is not always possible (eg. when using a remote filesystem) or quick (it depends on how many files are in the project folder).

Comment: Do the following similar shortcuts help : Ctrl+Shift+F, Ctrl+F or Ctl+T? As I'm not using VS Code I can't try it myself.

Comment: hi! 
`ctrl+shift+F` is the global search: it searches for **text** inside files matching your pattern. - `ctrl+F` is the current file search: it searches for **text** inside the current file. - `ctrl+T` is the symbol search: it searches for **classes/functions/whatever**, anywhere (if i'm not mistaken). - what i need is a gnome-search-tool/Everything Search/Explorer.exe-like search, listing files matching my query. i'm not looking for any particular file **contents**, just the name/path

Comment: Which operating system ?

Comment: windows, but also linux, and also virtual filesystems. it should be OS and FS agnostic..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, select the <kbd>Explorer</kbd> sidebar button or open it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> shortcut:
[image: Explorer]

Make sure it's focused by clicking on it. Then, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>. A search bar will appear. Enter the phrase that you want to match. Files matching it will get highlighted

You can lastly press the <kbd>Filter</kbd> button to only show the matched files:
[image: Filter]

Comment: works! but apparently there's a bug, it shows many many folders but when i expand them looking for my `.gitignore` files, the entire folder structure disappears, because it didn't contain the given file. also some times the folder is not even clickable, then i click something else, then it's clickable again. i think that's all a bit buggy

Comment: still, this is exactly what i was looking for. thanks. i'll report the bugs on github. have a nice day